# Linking object data but not the key frames

Tags: animation, scene

I want to link everything about the objects, except for the keyframes and animation, ideally looking to have scene 1, scene 2, scene 3, where each scene follows on from the next entirely. If your curious why I have choosen to have different scenes it is because I have paths that are followed, and they work easier if I can redo the paths for each scene.
I am pretty new to blender so any advise is welcome.
Thanks

Comment: I suggest you pick an object and display some of its fcurves showing how you switch from one constraint influence to another.  Sometimes people show how a candidate answer affected their actions.

Comment: Currently can't seem to know how to copy and paste an image in here, I had a look, and tried ctrl + G just opens my internet find. I will delete this comment once I know how haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion.
Know some features of Follow Path Constraint. The constraint ..

- active or inactive with keyframes ... see eye icon
- [influence] can be 0 to 1.0 with keyframes
- You can stack up many Path Constraints on a single object with judiciously placed keyframes.  Like relay runners passing a baton.
- Thus the object can travel down each path one at a time with no influence from the other.  You known when you place paths near each other the movement may seem continous

I suggest you use these 3 features to address your issues.

Comment: I did this and it worked well. I had to make sure I keyframed start and finish points on all curves. Eg using curve 1, to be followed first and curve 2 to be followed second by an object and say 100 frames each curve. then at frame 0 and 100, curve 1 influencer to be keyframed at 1, curve 2 influencer to be keyframed at 0. At frame 101 and 200, curve 1 influencer to be keyframed at 0 curve 2 influencer to be keyframed at 1. Problem solved for me!

Comment: If you feel that this candidate answer solved your problem you should mark it as the answer.  Otherwise you may downvote this candidate answer.  Thanks.